# stacked bar graph with and without factors in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a random segment of my data:

new_bic

```
            time  electrode     amps
2867    11.22972     A1_61 0.03181021
2868    11.23012     A1_73 0.04101065
2869    11.23024     A1_45 0.02053718
2870    11.23036     A1_47 0.13970933
2871    11.23036     A1_32 0.03532112
2872    11.23044     A1_81 0.03758630
2873    11.23044     A1_54 0.02858271
2874    11.23056     A1_76 0.08517757
2875    11.23064     A1_77 0.05597946
2876    11.23064     A1_56 0.03700752
2877    11.23068     A1_36 0.02002140
2878    11.23072     A1_21 0.12558076
2879    11.23076     A1_44 0.02107521
2880    11.23076     A1_68 0.09281007
2881    11.23084     A1_31 0.01390223
2882    11.23088     A1_66 0.02775229
2883    11.23096     A1_64 0.02810385
2884    11.23100     A1_46 0.01288512
2885    11.23104     A1_87 0.03736150
2886    11.23104     A1_34 0.27207340
2887    11.23112     A1_84 0.03999399
2888    11.23112     A1_63 0.02099964
```

And here's the code I ran to categorize electrode occurrences (i.e. how many amp recordings there are per electrode). It may be hard to see with this data but the electrodes actually occur *many* times throughout the entire dataset at different time points.

```
new_table <- within(new_bic, 
                electrode <- factor(electrode,
                                    levels=names(sort(table(electrode),
                                                      decreasing=F))))

pp <- ggplot(new_table,aes(x=electrode))+geom_bar() + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
 ylab("Firing Count") + xlab("Individual Electrodes") +ggtitle("Electrode Firing Count")
```

So I made a new_table with factored data "electrode" to be easily plotted in increasing order as a bar graph. This actually turned out nicely. However I wanted to include another piece of data and stack it on corresponding bars (which are each electrode). This piece of data that I want is the peak count for each electrode.

This is where I get stuck, my question is, and this will probably serve me in the future: is it possible to deal with factors and non factors in the same data frame and use this info for plotting categorical data? I'm not sure how this would work because the length of non factored items (e.g. the electrode count I have in the new_table above).

I want to stack a "peak count" for each electrode on the current bar graph, this should be an int for each electrode. Once I get these values I'm not sure where to put them so that I can use them in the plot, but it would be roughly something along the lines of:

```
for (elec in unique(new_bic$electrode))  
{
new_data <- new_bic[new_bic$electrode == elec,]
# remember to count the rows, because all we really want is a spike          count
peak_count <- nrow(findpeaks(new_data$amps))
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "peak count"?  The total height of each bar should be the total count of each electrode.

Comment: This is continuous data for about 360 seconds. So some of the "electrodes" have over 10K values, amongst the 10K there are probably a few hundred peaks. The findpeaks() function will detect a peaks. The bars just show how many times that particular electrode has a recording (so not necessarily a peak)

Comment: So peaks would be found by clustering signals for the same electrode that are close together in time?  And these values would be significantly less than the overall count?

Comment: They would be significantly less than the overall count, but it's not a clustering for multiple electrodes, just single electrodes. The current bar graph plots each individual electrode. Then yes for each individual electrode there will be peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize those data into a dataframe of three columns with the first column as `electrode` and the second column as total number of occurrences, and the third a factor called e.g. 'total'

Then create a similar data frame of electrode and peak count, and factor of 'peak'

Then rowbind them. Then plot stacked histogram.

Data should look like:

```
e.dat <- data.frame(electrode = c("e1", "e2", "e1", "e2"),
                   value = c(5,6,2,3),
                   type = c("total", "total", "peak", "peak"))
```

Then plot:

```
ggplot(e.dat, aes(x=electrode, y=value, fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: it's not apparently obvious to me how to create these three columns, having each row correspond to an electrode

Comment: `count(new_bic$electrode)` will give you the total number of instances of each electrode in the whole dataset. Then stick on another column with the same factor value for all values. I'm not sure I follow what your peak count is. Is it the highest value?

Comment: this is pretty good, except for it gives me a gradient in the stack as opposed to 2 opposing colors

Comment: are you using `fill=type` and `type` as a factor? Read through the excellent ggplot documentation to see if you're coding it right http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Comment: I'm a little more lost now than before. I have peaks they are a vector of values, I also have the total count of values which is another vector. Both are columns in my dataframe, converting these to factors with factor(x) is not working for me, I wanted a simple stacked histogram with 2 colors one for the total and one for peaks

Comment: so you have a 3 col data frame with columns electrode, total.count, and peak? (or similar names?) Try `melt` in the package `reshape2` with and you should have what you need